# Unhandled promise rejection network error when fetch data in React Native Expo app

Tags: spring-boot, react-native

I'm writing a React Native app for fetching data from REST endpoint. I already wrote a Spring Boot project and tested it perfectly with Postman. However when I use Axios to fetch data I received an error `Unhandled promise rejection: Network Error.` This is some of my code in project I run on my Android phone(not emulator) :

   `...
   componentDidMount(){
    console.log('hahah');
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dish/category/MainCourse').then(res => console.log(res));
  }
...`

When I changed `localhost:8080` to `10.0.0.2:8080` (this is solution I found on web), the error disappeared but the console didn't log any JSON response. I tired to use `@CrossOrigins` in my Spring Boot controller but it still doesn't work .I think the problem is idk how to change the `localhost:8080` to correct address. Anyone can solve me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `10.0.0.2` to the IP address your laptop/pc/machine hosting your Spring Boot server is on.

Comment: I usually use tunnel connection when running app. Is the address `exp://...` a correct one? Or I must use ipv4 address in ipconfig ??